# C# Print a specific string fom a website using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I need to get some text from a website we are using to get our data from. I finally found how, using HtmlAgilityPack and finding the Xpath I'm able to print out some text from the website.

But when I try to print the date and kind, which is coded like this:

```
<span class="span-line-break">zaterdag 05 december 2020</span> //Date
<span class="afvaldescr">Papier en karton</span> //Kind
```

I can't reach these two strings using my current code:

```
        public string Postalcode = "6093DK";
        public string Number = "2";
        public string Add = "";


            string url = "https://mijnafvalwijzer.nl/nl/" + Postalcode + "/" + Number + "/" + Add;
            var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
            
            string when = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"december-2020\"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/p/span[1]")[0].InnerText;
            string what = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"december-2020\"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/p/span[2]")[0].InnerText;

            textBox1.Text = when;
            textBox2.Text = what;
```

I figured that because the text is in a class I can not reach it.

Can someone help me find a more specific route to these strings?

The website is a Dutch garbadge calendar, don't mind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser inserts `tbody` for `table` element although it is not present in html. So here I just removed `tbody` from your XPath. In Chrome you can use network tab for viewing original response

[image]

```
string when = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"december-2020\"]/div/table[1]/tr/td[1]/a/p/span[1]")[0].InnerText;
string what = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"december-2020\"]/div/table[1]/tr/td[1]/a/p/span[2]")[0].InnerText;
```

You can also use shortened version of XPath using "//" and class selectors

```
string when = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"december-2020\"]//table[1]//span[@class=\"span-line-break\"]")[0].InnerText;
string what = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"december-2020\"]//table[1]//span[@class=\"afvaldescr\"]")[0].InnerText;
```